# Database gives "ORA-01109: Database not open" error when it IS open

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

- Running Oracle Database 12c on Windows Server 2012

Whenever I attempt to do a log switch (alter system archive log current), I am given the error in the title. Searching online shows the simple solution of opening the database via `alter database open`, then checking the status via `select status from v$instance` to ensure it is open will fix the issue. However, anytime I check the status, it is already in an OPEN state. `alter database open` doesn't do anything as it's already open.

Anyone have any idea why I'm encountering this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your database instance is open.

Your database open_status is a different thing, it could be open READ ONLY. The database is expected to be open for READ WRITE when you switch a logfile. So you might conclude that the error message is not complete.

```
select name, open_mode from v$database;
```

and since you are in 12c also check:

```
select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;
```

Most likely your database is not open for READ WRITE, as the error states. Question that remains is: why?

[Documentation about Oracle Database Instance](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/startup.htm#CNCPT89047)

When your database is open READ ONLY and try to perform a log switch, you get ORA-1109 : database not open.